# Unix Timestamp in Sencha Touch DatePickerField

Tags: timestamp, sencha-touch

I am trying to use a Unix Timestamp value as the default value for a DatePickerField in Sencha Touch. Here's the code I'm using for the form:

```
var profileForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    title: 'Profile',
    standardSubmit : false,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        title: '',
        instructions: 'Edit your profile above',
        defaults: { labelAlign: 'left', labelWidth: '40%' },
        items: [{ xtype: 'datepickerfield', name: 'dob', label: 'DoB', value: user.dob }]
    }]
});
```

I've tried adding `dataType: 'time'` to the declaration, but without success. Any thoughts on how this can be achieved without creating a custom Date class to handle timestamps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have used custom component [see this thread on Sencha forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?116383-Ext.ux.CustomPicker-Ext.ux.CustomPickerField-Ext.ux.TimePickerField&highlight=time%20field) since standard component doesn't work for time. Or a date-time picker [from this thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?115128-A-DateTimePicker).